# ASP.NET Precompile with non updateable UI

Tags: asp.net, .net, precompile, aspnet-compiler

I want to compile my ASP.NET web forms project into one single dll (which I think is possible) and copy that to the hosting server. As I want to protect all of my code.

In the solution explorer, if I right click the project and go to publish there are various options which I have played around with to precompile the site. The best result I have got so far is precompiled c# code and aspx pages. Unfortunately all of the javascript is still in its normal state.

I think I need to use the Merge all outputs into a single assembly option, but this unfortunately throws the errors: `Target GenerateAssemblyInfoFromExistingAssembleInfo Failed` 
and `@(_AspNetCompile_AssemblyInfo_Count) have 0 item(s) in the collection. It should only have 1 item(s)`

I've tried looking in the msdn docs for information on how to best do this, and there is some information relating to the command line, but I couldn't quite follow it.

I'm using .net 4.5 & visual studio express for web 2013.

If anyone can point me in the direction of a tutorial, or just give me some help. It would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Jim

Comment: You're trying to precompile your static script files as well? I doubt there's an option for that, outside of putting your javascript in aspx wrapper "pages", but that doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Comment: Look into minification or obfuscation if you're trying to protect your javascript. Those tools generally make script pretty unreadable, and you can work them into your build process. But I suppose it depends on who/what you're trying to protect your code from.

Comment: You could embed the script in the DLL as a resource and then write a handler to serve it up (I think). I've never done it.

Comment: This is duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44265423/msbuild-failure-when-precompilebeforepublish-is-enabled/46229469#46229469, see answer there.