# MSBuild Failure When PrecompileBeforePublish is enabled

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, precompile

**I'm using following command to compile a project using msbuild with pre compile enabled**

> msbuild C:\WebGoat.NET-master\WebGoat\WebGoat.NET.csproj
>   /p:OutputPath=bin /p:DeployOnBuild=true
>   /p:WebPublishMethod="FileSystem";PrecompileBeforePublish=true;EnableUpdateable=false;DebugSymbols=true
>   /p:UseMerge=true;WDPMergeOption="MergeAllOutputsToASingleAssembly";SingleAssemblyName="ContosoWebPrecompiled"

**Build is getting failed with following error message**

> "C:\WebGoat.NET-master\WebGoat\WebGoat.NET.csproj" (default target)
>   (1) -> (GenerateAssemblyInfoFromExistingAssembleInfo target) ->
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Transform\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AspNetCompileMerge
>   .targets(289,5): error : @(_AspNetCompile_AssemblyInfo_Count) have 0
>   item(s) in the collection. It should only have 1 i tem(s).
>   [C:\WebGoat.NET-master\WebGoat\WebGoat.NET.csproj]   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Transform\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AspNetCompileMerge
>   .targets(296,5): error : Target
>   GenerateAssemblyInfoFromExistingAssembleInfo Failed
>   [C:\WebGoat.NET-master\WebGoat\WebG oat.NET.csproj]

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 5):

You are **missing AssemblyInfo.cs in your Properties folder**.

Add this file using Visual Studio - Solution Explorer - Properties right-click - Add New Item - Assembly Info File.